# gcloud ml-engine predict is very slow on inference

Tags: google-cloud-ml-engine

I'm testing a segmentation model on gcloud and the inference is incredibly slow. It takes **3 min** to get the result (averaged over 5 runs). Same model runs ~2.5 s on my laptop when running through tf-serving.
Is it normal? I didn't find any mention in the documentation on how to define the instance type and it seems impossible to run inference on GPU.
The steps I'm using is fairly straightforward and follows the examples and tutorials:

```
gcloud ml-engine models create "seg_model"
gcloud ml-engine versions create v1 \
--model "seg_model" \
--origin $DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE \
--runtime-version 1.2 \
--staging-bucket gs://$BUCKET_NAME    
gcloud ml-engine predict --model ${MODEL_NAME} --version v1 --json-instances request.json
```

**Upd**: after running more experiments I found that redirecting output to a file gets the inference time down to 27s. Model output size is 512x512, which probably causes some delays on a client side. Although it is much lower than 3 min, it is still an order of magnitude slower than tf-serving.

Comment: My guess is you are hitting cold starts (although 3 mins seems long for even that). Did you enable logging for your model? If so you can check your logs to see if this was a "loading" request. Second request: when running locally can you try --tensorflow_session_parallelism=1 and see what happens to the runtime.?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I've found that one of the reasons of such slow performance was outputting to a console (see Upd section of my question). Also I followed your suggestion and enabled logging. Typical log message contains this line in payload section: modelLatency:  "21.820729s"
Also when I ran tf-serving with --tensorflow_session_parallelism=1 inference time for my model gets up to 7s from 2.5 s without that option

Comment: The service currently only offers serving for parallelism=1. We'd love to hear more about your particular needs if you're willing to answer a few questions like latency targets and price sensitivity. If so, send an email to cloudml-feedback@google.com

Comment: I've had the same issue which completely put me off on google cloud ML. I did however deployed the model using flask on cloud vm (GPU) which roughly takes about 1.5 seconds to a max 3 seconds for inference which is  much faster than 30 seconds on cloud ml. Also I hit series of request at first and as soon as the response arrived, I hit few more requests which took again the same amount of time. So its definitely not cold start issue. Is it solved yet ?